# how to add footer to first page , change color of the footer line and make some text in footer bold?

Tags: header-footer, color, fancyhdr, footer

I am not getting a footer on the first page of the article; I need to change the colour of the footer line and to make some text in footer bold. `\textbf` is not working .

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[CO]{
    \textbf{ Propriety note :} This document is Proprietary to Titan. \\
    This document shall not be shared, copied in whole or in
    part by anyone unless approved by authorized
    personnel of Titan in writing.}


\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2pt}

\newdateformat{monthyeardate}{%
  \monthname[\THEMONTH], \THEYEAR}


\title{%
     PROJECT REQUIREMENT DOCUMENT \\
     \large \vspace{3mm}
     by Central Technology Services(CTS)  \\
      Titan Company Limited }
\author{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This question is very similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30228/5763. Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: Related: [custom footer on title page using \maketitle and book document class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199356/124842)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**: Using [this question as a reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30228/custom-first-page-with-fancyhdr), you can make your footer show up on the page, and also the bold text will work.  You have to setup a `\fancypagestyle` containing your changes, then call `\thispagestyle` after `\maketitle` in the document.  As for making the footer line a different color, [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300275/cant-change-the-colour-of-the-line-in-the-header-fancyhdr) was helpful.  You can retain the `\footrule` command to change the footer line with the command `\let\oldfootrule\footrule` and then change the color with the line `\renewcommand{\footrule}{{\color{red}\oldfootrule}}` inside the new `fancypagestyle` that you're setting up.  I also used the line `\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}` to cause the line to show up.  Feel free to customize the color and size of your line this way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\let\oldfootrule\footrule

% define a style for the special footer
\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[CO]{
        \textbf{ Propriety note :} This document is Proprietary to Titan. \\
        This document shall not be shared, copied in whole or in
        part by anyone unless approved by authorized
        personnel of Titan in writing.}
    \renewcommand{\footrule}{{\color{red}\oldfootrule}}%
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
}

\newdateformat{monthyeardate}{%
  \monthname[\THEMONTH], \THEYEAR}


\title{%
     PROJECT REQUIREMENT DOCUMENT \\
     \large \vspace{3mm}
     by Central Technology Services(CTS)  \\
      Titan Company Limited }
\author{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

% make this page have defined style
\thispagestyle{mystyle}



\end{document}
```

I hope this helps!